# Declare array size in header file without #define's

Tags: c++, arrays, header

I have a code a following (simplified version):

```
#define MESSAGE_SIZE_MAX 1024
#defined MESSAGE_COUNT_MAX 20

class MyClass {
public:
   .. some stuff
private:
   unsigned char m_messageStorage[MESSAGE_COUNT_MAX*MESSAGE_SIZE_MAX];
};
```

I don't like defines, which are visible to all users of MyCalss.

How can I do it in C++ style?

Thanks
Dima

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick to get such things into the `class` definition is,

```
// public:
enum {MESSAGE_SIZE_MAX=1024, MESSAGE_COUNT_MAX=20};
```

I never liked `#defines` to be used like constants.
Its always a good practice to use `enum`.

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you simply use a constant?

```
const int message_size_max = 1024;
```

Note that unlike C, C++ makes constant variables in global scope have static linkage by default.

The constant variable above is a constant expression and as such can be used to specify array sizes.

```
char message[message_size_max];
```

Comment: It will be statically linked in all objects using MyClass and thus adding garbage to them.

Comment: If it does, then you have an ancient compiler or you're taking the constant's address somewhere.